# how to increase Y-Axis height in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I need to deal with large array data in Highcharts and I need to increase the height in `Y-Axis` and width in `X-Axis` with scrollbar. How to do this?

[image]

My JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ngendk2o/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually increase the `height` and `width` of your chart. For example, use:

```
chart: {
    /* ... */,
    height: 800,
    width: 2000
}
```

It will automatically add scroll-bars to your page.

See your JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ngendk2o/4/

Comment: can i do it per line? For example I don't need 800px if my Y-Axis only contains 5 rows.

Comment: Well, in your case, you could use your arrays length to determine the height. For example, use `height: tasks.length * 30`. JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ngendk2o/7/